# Windows XP limited users access shared folder

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, windows-xp, limited-user-account

How I can access a shared folder from the network as a limited user?

Comment: If that folder is shared for everyone you should be able to see it

Comment: @Ioan: Its shared for everyone but I'm not able to see it from another PC which is connected to the same workgroup.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that it's asking you to log in. Then you have to adjust the local security policy for the machine where the file is shared on. If that is on Windows XP you must make sure that under ***Access this computer from the network*** you have *Everyone* and also make sure that *Guest* is not under ***Deny access to this computer from the network***.

[image: Local Security Policy]

So, in this case, the problem is not on the machine accessing the file(s) but on the machine that is doing the sharing.

Comment: Still I'm not able to access the shared folder from XP limited user after following your tips

Comment: And if you switch to an administrator, you can ?

Comment: Yes, if I'm accessing the shared folder with a Administrator account

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, this is a weird issue, and an annoying one!

Basically, File sharing will always attempt to first log you on with your current credentials.

This is good in environments such as a domain as it means you don't need to re log on, and it is also good in some workgroups as you can just create your account on the remote computer and access files in a share, again, without logging on... However, in order to share files to anonymous users, the guest account is used.

So, basically, I am guessing your machine is attempting to log on to the remote share with the guest account.

The quickest workaround I can suggest is to map a network drive and click on `Connect using a different user name`. You can then use the correct username and password to log on.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to connect using a limited user?

Answer (score 0):

Old problem but found the solution. It's disabled consciously. You can try searching in registry under user settings: HKEY_USERS -> User that have folders disabled -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Policies -> Explorer and there should be property "nocommongroups" that controls it. If enabled, the Programs menu doesn't contain items from the All Users profile and shows only items from the current user's user profile. Remove or disable it if you are sure that is needed. Right HKEY_USER you can identify under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> MICROSOFT -> Windows NT -> ProfileList, you just select any profile there and identify it by correct ProfileImagePath